# Workflow email sent from user who created item

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, email

I have a workflow whereby when a user creates an item in a list an email is sent. I am using Sharepoint designer 2010 for this. Is there any way to have the email address be that of the user who created the item instead of the standard Sharepoint address? (Any solution is welcome - does not need to be SPD2010) thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can send email from SPD 2010 by specifying a from address. I write server code to achieve this. 
[Sending email programmatically in SharePoint](http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/sending-email-programmatically-in-sharepoint)